# Remove trailing zeros from a string

Tags: php

I would like to remove trailing zero's according to the following rules:

- The input number will always have 4 decimal places
- The output number should always have between 2 and 4 decimals
- If the last two digits after the decimal is a zero, then remove both of them
- If the last digit after the decimal is a zero, then remove it

Examples:

- 1.0000 -> 1.00
- 1.4000 -> 1.40
- 1.4100 -> 1.41
- 1.4130 -> 1.413
- 1.4136 -> 1.4136

I have considered the following:

```
if (substr($number, -2) == '00') return substr($number, 0, 4);
if (substr($number, -1) == '0') return substr($number, 0, 5);
return $number;
```

Are there any better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
return preg_replace('/0{1,2}$/', '', $number);

$strings = array ('1.4000', '1.4100', '1.4130', '1.4136', '1.4001', '1.0041');
foreach ($strings as $number) {
  echo "$number -> " . preg_replace('/0{0,2}$/', '', $number) . "\n";
}
```

Produces:

```
1.4000 -> 1.40
1.4100 -> 1.41
1.4130 -> 1.413
1.4136 -> 1.4136
1.4001 -> 1.4001
1.0041 -> 1.0041
```

Comment: `{1,2}` should be enough here.

Comment: @jcsanyi You need to use `{2,}?` to make it non-greedy.

Comment: How about `1.4001` or `1.0041`??

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on Barmar's solution that will work even if the input strings don't always have exactly 4 decimal places. It won't add missing zeroes, but it won't strip any more than it should either.

```
return preg_replace('/(\.[0-9]{2,}?)0*$/', '$1', $number);
```

As an example:

```
$strings = array(
    '1.4000',
    '1.4100',
    '1.4130',
    '1.4136',
    '1.0',
    '1.00',
    '1.000',
    '10000',
);
foreach ($strings as $number) {
    $fixed = preg_replace('/(\.[0-9]{2,}?)0*$/', '$1', $number);
    echo "{$number} -> {$fixed}\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
1.4000 -> 1.40
1.4100 -> 1.41
1.4130 -> 1.413
1.4136 -> 1.4136
1.0 -> 1.0
1.00 -> 1.00
1.000 -> 1.00
10000 -> 10000
```

Comment: Regular expressions, lolz. You're must be nutz or Perl-programmers.

Comment: Know this is an old answer, but... `even if the input strings don't always have exactly 4 decimal places` so why does `1.000010000` turn into `1010000` ?

Answer (score 0):

And now for something completely different...

```
<?php
$crlf = "\n";
$input = array('1.4000', '1.4300', '1.2340', '1.4012', '1.0034', '1.2', '1.23456');
foreach ($input as $in) {
  for($n = 4; $n>2; $n--) {
    $f1 = (float)round($in, $n);
    $f2 = (float)round($in, $n-1);
    if ($f1 !== $f2) break;
  }
  echo "for in = ".$in." out is ".number_format($in, $n) . $crlf;
}
?>
```

Output:

```
for in = 1.4000 out is 1.40
for in = 1.4300 out is 1.43
for in = 1.2340 out is 1.234
for in = 1.4012 out is 1.4012
for in = 1.0034 out is 1.0034
for in = 1.2 out is 1.20
for in = 1.23456 out is 1.2346
```

Note that this will behave as expected for properly formatted numbers (with exactly four digits after the decimal), but it will still behave when the numbers were not correctly formatted. Not quite what was asked for - but it's often better to have a robust solution than a minimalist one...